# How to prove that the Maclaurin expansion of $f(x^n)$ is equal to the Maclaurin expansion of $f(t)$ with substitution $t=x^n$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

It seems to be intuitively true, however I still cannot find a satisfying proof to convince myself.
At the same time, is there any more general statement about this fact?

Comment: When you say "Maclaurin expansion", are you assuming that it converges in a neighborhood of $0$, or are you just talking about the formal power series you get using the derivatives of of $f$?  (The result is true either way, but what you need to do to prove it is different.)

Comment: In my mind, I was thinking about the power series derived using derivatives of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

An outline and a reference:

There is a general formula for the $k$th derivative of $f\circ g$ known as [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula). Use this to write down a formula for the $k$th derivative of $f(x^n)$ in terms of derivatives of $f$.

For a Maclaurin series, you must evaluate these derivatives at $x=0$. If you have used Faà di Bruno carefully, you will be able to show that evaluating at $x=0$ results in $0$ except when $k$ is a multiple of $n$. And you will also be able to show that when $k$ is a multiple of $n$, the derivative works out to exactly what it needs to be to match the result of simply substituting $t=x^n$ into the Maclaurin series for $f(t)$.

Comment: That is a formidable formula

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The derivatives of $f(x^n)$ are

$$\frac{df(x^n)}{dx}=nx^{n-1}f'(x^n),\\
\frac{d^2f(x^n)}{dx^2}=n^2x^{2n-2}f''(x^n)+n(n-1)x^{n-2}f'(x^n),\\
\frac{d^3f(x^n)}{dx^3}=n^3x^{3n-3}f'''(x^n)+2n^2(n-1)x^{2n-3}f''(x^n)+n(n-1)(n-2)x^{n-3}f'(x^n),\\
\cdots$$

Hence, when evaluating at $x=0$, the first nonzero derivative is

$$\frac{d^{(n)}f(x^n)}{dx}(0)=n!f'(0).$$

Continuing this way you should find the next nonzero to be

$$\frac{d^{(2n)}f(x^{n})}{dx}(0)=\frac{(2n)!}{n!}f''(0).$$

Comment: I have to say it is not easy to prove the general formula of $n$th nonzero derivative.

Comment: @Rikka: mh, I wouldn't say so. Clearly for the $m^{th}$ derivative the exponents are of the form $kn-m$ so they are zero only when $n|m$. The value of the coefficients is harder to address, but you can establish a recurrence relation and you know the answer beforehand: $m!/n!$ which is a mere falling factorial.

Comment: @Rikka: anyway, your question was more on the intuitive side I guess. It is an easy act of faith to admit that the coefficients will match.